# Anconva or Anova for multifactor analysis

Tags: anova, ancova, similarities, mancova

I have non-normal plankton community data, where rows are sites and columns are species (dependent) and a few factors.

I want to check the influence of season on community (dis)similarities but am cautious that night and year have an effect. Ideally I would like to determine which factors cause variance and how they might interact.

I have performed a simple anosim to test between seasonal groupings, but want a more comprehensive analysis between all factors. An anosim between day and night suggests it causes 10% of the variance.

After hours (days) of trawling the internet I am quite confused as to how to proceed, if I have missed something simple please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Where are the data from? Do your day and night lengths change throughout the year?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the reply. Sorry I should have explained, day/night is a factor. Community matrix are plankton data. I have three factors.

Comment: After more research, I am performing a permanova (adonis in r) but realise these do not account for covariance, hence my investigation into the above.